# Partition function for nonlinear sigma model

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

Let $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ be Riemannian manifolds. The action for the [nonlinear sigma model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_sigma_model) with base $M$ and target $N$ is simply the [Dirichlet energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_map) (i.e. harmonic map energy) for maps $\phi:M\to N$:
$$
S(\phi)=\int_M\|d\phi\|^2\;dV_g.
$$
Critical points of $S$ are *harmonic maps*. For example, when the target $(N,h)$ is just $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric, then critical points of $S$ are *harmonic functions*, i.e. those maps $\phi:M\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\Delta_g\phi=0$.

The partition function for the nonlinear sigma model is formally given by the path integral
$$
Z=\int e^{-S(\phi)}\; D\phi.
$$

**Question:** How can we rigorously define $Z$ for general target manifolds $(N,h)$?

Note that there are cases when $Z$ is well defined:

**Special case: $(N,h)=(\mathbb{R},g_{\mathrm{std}})$** In this case, we can use [zeta function regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization). The [Minakshisundaram–Pleijel zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minakshisundaram%E2%80%93Pleijel_zeta_function) $\zeta:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$
\zeta(s)=\sum_{\lambda\in\mathrm{Spec}(\Delta_g)\setminus \{0\}} |\lambda|^{-s} \qquad\qquad \text{for}\qquad \mathrm{Re}(s)>\dim M/2
$$ is holomorphic for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>\dim M/2$ and analytically extends to a meromorphic function on all of $\mathbb{C}$ which is regular at $s=0$. We then define the partition function by
$$
Z=\det \Delta_g^{-1}=\mathrm{exp}(\zeta'(0)).
$$
Can this method be extended to general target manifolds?